# Finding pixel or map size of TextSymbol using ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET?

Tags: symbology, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

I'm using the ArcGIS runtime SDK for .Net, version 10.2.7.

I have a point graphic that is symbolised with a TextSymbol.  I would like to add a separate polygon graphic to the graphics overlay that covers the extent of the text symbol.

What I have tried is below.  It works fairly well, but there is a small difference between the text and the polygon.

```
 var symbol = GetGraphicSymbol();
 if (symbol == null)
     return;
 var text = symbol.Font;

 var size = graphics.MeasureString(symbol.Text, 
     new Font(text.FontFamily, 
              (float)text.FontSize, 
              FontStyle.Regular, 
              GraphicsUnit.Document));
 if (size.Width == 0 || size.Height == 0)
     return;

 var width = mapView.UnitsPerPixel * size.Width;
 var height = mapView.UnitsPerPixel * size.Height;
```

I understand that on any scale change the polygon graphic would need to be recalculated.

Comment: Have a read of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37667/getting-annotation-text-geometry-as-polygon-using-arcobjects/37677#37677

Comment: @MichaelStimson that seems to be how to find the value through ArcObjects.  I need to do it through the 10.2.7 ArcGIS runtime for wpf.

Comment: I was under the impression that there is little difference between runtime and ArcObjects. Does that interface not exist in your SDK? I can remember doing a similar thing but have misplaced the code.. I was looking for clashing annotation and became constantly frustrated that the polygons generated weren't exactly the same as the text, they were slightly smaller (about 90%) and ended up buffering by a small amount, that might be hacky but it worked.

Comment: The .Net runtime doesn't expose interfaces...that I know of.  More info ->  https://developers.arcgis.com/net/10-2/

Comment: I must be, I've not used either and am relying on hearsay.

Comment: The Runtime and ArcObjects are two VERY different beasts - pretty much everything is different, as they have very different architectures and very different goals.

Comment: If you just need to add a background to the text, the textsymbol has a background property and will render a box around it. Can you use that instead? Alternatively create a swatch from the text symbol, and measure the size of the image generated (just beware that this is quite expensive if you need to do it for a lot of texts)

Comment: @dotMorten, create swatch worked.  Thanks!  I saw the method in the doc, but must have miss understood it.  I thought it would return an image source that was 32x32.