# Getting Annotation Text Geometry Only (without leader line) as Polygon Using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, annotation

I have an annotation feature that also has a line callout (see picture).  I need to use ArcObjects to get the polygon that surrounds ONLY the text (not the line callout).  The following link is very similar to the problem I am having.

[Getting Annotation Text Geometry as Polygon Using ArcObjects?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37667/getting-annotation-text-geometry-as-polygon-using-arcobjects?newreg=6cc1115f43fe4fc6bd72501bb1d8238d)

[image: Annotation Shape]

However the solution is to use the QueryOutline.  The problem with the QueryOutline method is that I must pass a IDisplay parameter.  When I pass the IDisplay of the mxd, the polygon that is returned has a different size based on the zoom level of my mxd.

So if I'm zoomed in at 1:1000 the polygon that is returned is bigger than when my mxd is zoomed in at 1:2400.  How do I know what level to zoom in so I can get the exact size of the polygon?  Or if there is another to only get the text polygon that would work for me as well.

Comment: By "IDisplay of the mxd" do you mean the IActiveView.ScreenDisplay of the map?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant

Comment: Did you try [IDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ScaleRatio](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IDisplayTransformation_ScaleRatio.htm) ?

Comment: How do I use this?